# How to fix the layout of the mobile version of my website?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem here about my layout, if its in PC it looks good, but when its in MOBILE it looks horrible, can some one help me about this problem please?

**PC**

[image: pc]

**Mobile**

[image: mobile]

Comment: THERES THE LINK OF THE IMAGE PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: Please send the code what ifyou havetried?

Comment: Please copy  that code from html and put that code in question u r sending image of code also have you ever seen any question on stackoverflow where code i image format